# How to override methods when inheriting from a class that uses templates?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to properly write a class that both inherits from a class that uses templates and also overrides a virtual method.  When I attempt to create an instance of this class, Visual Studio is giving me an error saying that

```
object of abstract type PropertyReal is not allowed: 
pure virtual function "Property<T>::propertyId [width t=qreal]" has no overrider
```

This is my code

```
template <typename T>
class Property
{
    T  _value;

public:
    Property(T initValue);
    ~Property();

    virtual QString propertyId() = 0;

    virtual T value() { return _value; }
    virtual void setValue(T value) { _value = value; }
};


template<typename T> 
Property::Property(T initValue)
    :_value(initValue)
{
}


template<typename T> 
Property::~Property()
{
}




class PropertyReal : public Property<qreal>
{
    static const QString ID;

public:
    PropertyReal();
    ~PropertyReal();

    template <qreal>
    QString propertyId() { return ID; }
};

const QString PropertyReal::ID = "real";

PropertyReal::PropertyReal()
{
}

PropertyReal::~PropertyReal()
{
}



class RectComp : Component
{
public:
    static const QString ID;

    PropertyReal _width;

public:
    RectComp();
    ~RectComp();

    QString componentId() { return ID;  }
};
```

The error is occurring when I declare the field `PropertyReal _width`.  How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
class PropertyReal : public Property<qreal>
{
    static const QString ID;

public:
    PropertyReal();
    ~PropertyReal();

    // note: this is not a template!
    QString propertyId() override { return ID; }
};
```

[`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword is not necessary, but adding it is a good practice.

In your example `Property` is not a class, but a class *template*. You're deriving `PropertyReal` from an (implicitly) instantiated class `Property<qreal>` - when you used `T` in `Property`, you should use `qreal` in `PropertyReal`.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `template <qreal>` part.

Write simply

```
QString propertyId() { return ID; }
```

The point is that virtual ant template methods doesn't match. You can't make a virtual template method and a template method can't override a virtual class.

For other virtual methods

```
virtual T value() { return _value; }
virtual void setValue(T value) { _value = value; }
```

that are depending from the template `T` parameter of the `Property` class, you have to match the template parameter you have passed to the base class.

I mean... because `PropertyReal` inherit from `Property<qreal>`, you can override `value()` and `setValue()` as follows

```
qreal value () { /* something */ }
void setValue (qreal value) { /* something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QString propertyId() override { return ID; }
```

should work just fine.

See simplified example: [ideone](https://ideone.com/VGf9lh)